# Duplicated records from SELECT DISTINCT COUNT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

```
 ------------------------------------
| dbo.Katigories  | dbo.Products     |
|-----------------|------------------|
| product_id      | product_id       |
| Cat_Main_ID     | F_material       |
| Cat_Sub_ID      |                  |
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I want to `COUNT` how many unique products (from the `Products` table) have as `Cat_Main_ID`=111, have as `Cat_Sub_ID`=222, and have as `F_material`=10

I have tried the following `SELECT COUNT` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS METR_AN_EXEI_001
FROM dbo.Products P
INNER JOIN dbo.Katigories K
ON P.product_id = K.product_id
AND
K.Cat_Main_ID = 111
AND
P.F_material = 10
AND
K.Cat_Sub_ID = 222
```

The above statement is working, and counts the correct products, but is giving me duplicated records.
For example: When a product belongs to only 1 category the result of my count is correct and I am getting the number 1 as a result. But when a product belongs to more than one category then the result of the count is incorrect, depending on how many categories the product belongs. I know that the reason for the duplicates is that some of my products belong simultaneously to more than one category or sub category, so I am getting incorrect count results.

It will be truly appreciated if someone could help me with the syntax of my `COUNT` statement, in order to get the correct number of products (without duplicates) from my `Products` table.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!-----------------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!

Dear all.

Please forgive me for the inconvenience!

I'm so stupid, that I was placing your code in the wrong point in my page. Eventually almost all of the suggestions were correct.

Now I have a problem and I do not know which of the answers I choose to be right. All of them are correct!

A very big thank to all of you and I apologize again to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to count distinct products use `count(distinct ...)`. Something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.product_id) AS METR_AN_EXEI_001
FROM dbo.Products P
INNER JOIN dbo.Katigories K
ON P.product_id = K.product_id
AND
K.Cat_Main_ID = 111
AND
P.F_material = 10
AND
K.Cat_Sub_ID = 222
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose grouping should  be approporate compared to distinct in this case

```
 SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id)  
 METR_AN_EXEI_001
 FROM dbo.Products P
 INNER JOIN dbo.Katigories K
 ON P.product_id = K.product_id
 AND
  K.Cat_Main_ID = 111
 AND
 P.F_material = 10
 AND
  K.Cat_Sub_ID = 222
  GROUP BY P.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Can u try it using subselect to count, like this:

```
DECLARE @Katigories TABLE ( product_id int , Cat_Main_ID int , Cat_Sub_ID int )
DECLARE @Products TABLE( product_id int , F_material int )

INSERT INTO @Products (product_id,F_material) VALUES (1, 10)
INSERT INTO @Products (product_id,F_material) VALUES (2, 10)
INSERT INTO @Products (product_id,F_material) VALUES (3, 15)

INSERT INTO @Katigories ( product_id ,Cat_Main_ID ,Cat_Sub_ID ) VALUES  ( 1,111, 222 )
INSERT INTO @Katigories ( product_id ,Cat_Main_ID ,Cat_Sub_ID ) VALUES  ( 1,123, 223 )
INSERT INTO @Katigories ( product_id ,Cat_Main_ID ,Cat_Sub_ID ) VALUES  ( 1,444, 222 )
INSERT INTO @Katigories ( product_id ,Cat_Main_ID ,Cat_Sub_ID ) VALUES  ( 2,133, 223 )

SELECT 
    P.product_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Katigories WHERE product_id = P.product_id AND Cat_Main_ID=111 AND Cat_Sub_ID=222 AND P.F_material=10) AS METR_AN_EXEI_001
FROM @Products P
```

---